# Condense mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any way to condense this into one line:

```
RewriteRule \.html+(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule \.htm+(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule \.(html|htm)+(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

But it didn't have the desired effect. Basically I want to check if either the .html and .htm extension is part of the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have that plus sign there? It should be like this:

```
RewriteRule \.html(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule \.htm(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

and condensed:

```
RewriteRule \.html?(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

or:

```
RewriteRule \.(html|htm)(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I have not idea what the + sign is for! rewrites are not my strong point.

Comment: it is for 1..n repeats of the previous character or block of characters, e.g. ab+ matches ab, aba, abba, (htm)+ matches htm, htmhtm etc. But in your example it didn't make sense so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Can you recommend a good place to learn about the rewrite syntax

Comment: Just see the Apache doc - mod_rewrite ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html ) . But if you mean the syntax of the regular expressions, just look at PCRE - perl compatible regular expressions. See `man perlre` on linux, PHP documentation or google.